# Braintree: can users update their vaulted customer information?

Tags: javascript, braintree

I'm using the Braintree v3 javascript client implementation.  After my server returns to me the vaulted information on the customer : payment method, billing address, etc so I can pre-populate some fields on the UI, is there a way on the client side to update the information,  such as billing address, if they want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Braintree. If you need more assistance, please reach out to [Braintree Support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact).

You can make a server side API call that updates the customer's information based on what they enter into your client-side form. Here is an example of making this call using the Node.js sdk:

```
gateway.customer.update("theCustomerId", {
  firstName: "New First Name",
  lastName: "New Last Name"
}, function (err, result) {
});
```

A link with more details is located in Braintree's [Support Documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/update/node).

Comment: how would the client do this?  Would I have to send the form data fields to the server side customer.update() call?

Comment: Yes, you would send the data from your client-side form to your server, then make the call to update the customer info.